# How to use Dependency Injection in case of no start up class C#?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef, dependency-management

I have the child-parent class relationship but I **don’t have any startup class** to resolve the dependency explicitly. In addition, I **don't want to remove empty constructor** from child class as it has a dependency. How and Where can I configure my containers to achieve dependency injection implementation?

Currently, I am achieving it using below logic for unit testing mocking purpose.

Is it possible to dynamically resolve dependency using MEF C# or through base lass. Any help appreciated.

e.g.

```
 public class child : Parent
 {
       private ILogger _logger;
       public child() : this(new FileLogger()) { }

       public child(ILogger logger)
       {
            _logger = logger;
       }

       public void DoWork()
       {
             //Perform Work.
             _logger.Log("Log Work Here");
       }
 }

public abstract class Parent
{
        //Common Operations
}

public interface ILogger
{
        void Log(string message);
}

//Multiple Inplementation for ILogger
public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
      public void Log(string message)
      {
            //Log into file.
      }
}
```

Comment: try register your dependencies to main method

Comment: Any examples on this?

Comment: If you are using .net core than I guess you must need to add startup class to web builder to configure services.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don’t have any startup class to resolve the dependency explicitly"? Every application has a start-up location where the first code runs. This is the place where you would wire up your dependencies. This location is called the [Composition Root](http://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Comment: I have the similar implementation like aws lambda where I don't have startup class - E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984918/aws-lambda-environment-variables-and-dependency-injection